# The reason to write "o'clock"

Tags: contractions

What does mean or why we write the letter "o'" with clock?  Is there any letter instead of the apostrophe?

Comment: The original expression is *of the clock*, progressively contracted to *o' th'* and finally to  *o'*.

Comment: @StoneyB: Preettttty sure that should be an answer, no?

Answer (score 6):

*O'clock* is a historical contraction of *of the clock*.

This *o'* contraction for *of* also shows up in:

> jack-o'-lantern, will-o'-wisp/will-o'-the-wisp, cat o' nine tails, ...

This isn't a very productive contraction though.